# Comunication between JS and JavaFX after reload

Tags: javafx

I want to call javafx functions from javascript on my HTML. I do the following (and it works correctly):

```
JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
win.setMember("app", new MyController(this.webEngine));

URL url = getClass().getResource("page1.html");            
this.webEngine.load(url.toExternalForm());
```

Inside the page1.html i can call functions from **MyController** with JavaScript using the *app* object:

```
app.hello();
```

Then, in some moment I change the displaying page like this:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("page2.html");            
this.webEngine.load(url.toExternalForm());
```

The problem is that in page2.html i can't call any function from **MyController**. I've tried to recreate the object app (before and after the page change) but it doesn't work.

How can I maintain the interaction within JS and JavaFX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. After loading a new page, the DOM is replaced so the `window` object change too. The original `JSObject` object, that was created on the previous page, is pointing to a wrong `window` so JS can not call its methods. Is need to create a new `JSObject` object every time that the page is reloaded.

To recreate the new `JSObject` object you have to be sure that the page is completly loaded, so:

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
    if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
        JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
        win.setMember("app", new MyController(this.webEngine));
    }
});

URL url = getClass().getResource("page2.html");            
webEngine.load(url.toExternalForm());
```